# SQL - Get additional records apart from records filtered in where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a 3 tables:

```
TableA - Id, TableB_id

TableB - Id, Name, TableC_id

TableC - Id, Valid
```

Valid can be 0 or 1.

There is one to many relatioship between TableA -> TableB & between TableB -> TableC.

I want to fetch all the records of TableA & TableB for which TableC.valid = 0.

Plus, records from TableA & TableB, even if there are no associated records in TableC.

I've written query for first part, but how to include second condition? (If possible without thr use of union)

**Query:**

```
Select 
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.name,
    c.id
from
    TableA a
    left join TableB b on a.TableB_id = b.id
    left join TableC c on b.TableC_id = c.id
where
    c.valid = 1;
```

Comment: Do `left join TableC c on b.TableC_id = c.id
AND c.valid = 1;` to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: The predicate `c.valid = 1` defeats the left joins, effectively converting them to inner joins. Place that predicate in the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `left join`, conditions on all but the first tables usually go in the `on` clauses:

```
Select a.id, b.id, b.name, c.id
from TableA a left join
     TableB b 
     on a.TableB_id = b.id left join
     TableC c
     on b.TableC_id = c.id and c.valid = 1;
```