# Get only LHS data for specific where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I asked a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305024/sql-get-additional-records-apart-from-records-filtered-in-where-condition?noredirect=1#comment110194661_62305024) question, but later realised the use case I asked was wrong. So now asking it correctly.

I've a 3 tables:

```
TableA - Id, TableB_id

TableB - Id, Name, TableC_id

TableC - Id, Valid
```

Valid can be 0 or 1.

There is one to many relatioship between TableA -> TableB & between TableB -> TableC.

I want to fetch all the records of TableA & TableB for which TableC.valid = 0.

Plus, if TableC has all the records as valid = 1 for a TableB, then only fetch data for TableA & TableB.

In other words, data is like:

**TableA:**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | TableB_Id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |       100 |
|  2 |       101 |
|  3 |       101 |
|  4 |       102 |
+----+-----------+
```

**TableB:**

```
+-----+------+-----------+
| Id  | Name | TableC_id |
+-----+------+-----------+
| 100 | Adam |       200 |
| 101 | Nick |       201 |
| 102 | Jim  |       202 |
+-----+------+-----------+
```

**TableC:**

```
+-----+-------+
| Id  | Valid |
+-----+-------+
| 200 |     0 |
| 201 |     0 |
| 202 |     1 |
+-----+-------+
```

So result would be:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
| TableA_ID | TableB_ID | Name | TableC_ID |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
|         1 |       100 | Adam | 200       |
|         2 |       101 | Nick | 201       |
|         3 |       101 | Nick | 201       |
|         4 |       102 | Jim  | null      |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

I've written query for first part, but how to include second condition?

**Query:**

```
Select 
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.name,
    c.id
from
    TableA a
    inner join TableB b on a.TableB_id = b.id
    inner join TableC c on b.TableC_id = c.id
where
    c.valid = 1;
```

Comment: "...if TableC has all the records as valid = 1 for a TableB" I wish I could understand that!

Answer (score 1):

Use below (Oracle DB used)

```
Select
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.name,
    decode(c.valid,0,c.id,null)  c_id,
from
    TableA a
    inner join TableB b on a.TableB_id = b.id
   inner join TableC c on b.TableC_id = c.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your claim you have a

*one to many relatioship* between **TableC -> TableB** and

*one to many relatioship* between **TableB -> TableA**

I assume that `ID` is a *primary key* and the columns `TableB_id`, `TableC_id` are thefore *foreign keys*.

So the natural way of writing a query would be a join **C --> B --> A**

I'm using *outer join* to also show cases where data in B or A are missing (feel free to fall back to inner join if this is not required).

The only unusual requirement is that you need to hide the ID of the table `C` if the row is not valid, which can be easily done with a `CASE` statement

```
select 
 case when c.valid = 0 then c.id end tableC_id,
 b.id tableB_id,
 a.id tableA_id
from c
left outer join b on c.id = b.TableC_id
left outer join a on b.id = a.tableb_id;

 TABLEC_ID  TABLEB_ID  TABLEA_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
       200        100          1
       201        101          2
       201        101          3
                  102          4
```

Note that I reordered the columns to show the correct hierarchy and removed the column not relevant for the discussion.